# Undefined Vector in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, vector

I am learning Java and so far I have reached `Vector`s, but my IDE seems to give me some issues, so I want to ask you for a possible solution to my problem.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Vector {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // initial size is 3, increment is 2
        Vector v = new Vector(3, 2);
        System.out.println("Initial size: " + v.size());
        System.out.println("Initial capacity: " + v.capacity());
        v.addElement(new Integer(1));
        v.addElement(new Integer(2));
        v.addElement(new Integer(3));
        v.addElement(new Integer(4));
        System.out.println("Capacity after four additions: " + v.capacity());

        v.addElement(new Double(5.45));
        System.out.println("Current capacity: " + v.capacity());
        v.addElement(new Double(6.08));
        v.addElement(new Integer(7));
        System.out.println("Current capacity: " + v.capacity());
        v.addElement(new Float(9.4));
        v.addElement(new Integer(10));
        System.out.println("Current capacity: " + v.capacity());
        v.addElement(new Integer(11));
        v.addElement(new Integer(12));
        System.out.println("First element: " + (Integer) v.firstElement());
        System.out.println("Last element: " + (Integer) v.lastElement());
        if (v.contains(new Integer(3)))
            System.out.println("Vector contains 3.");
        // enumerate the elements in the vector.
        Enumeration vEnum = v.elements();
        System.out.println("\nElements in vector:");
        while (vEnum.hasMoreElements())
            System.out.print(vEnum.nextElement() + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor Vector(int, int) is undefined
    The method size() is undefined for the type Vector
    The method capacity() is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Integer) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Integer) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Integer) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Integer) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method capacity() is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Double) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method capacity() is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Double) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Integer) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method capacity() is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Float) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Integer) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method capacity() is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Integer) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method addElement(Integer) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method firstElement() is undefined for the type Vector
    The method lastElement() is undefined for the type Vector
    The method contains(Integer) is undefined for the type Vector
    The method elements() is undefined for the type Vector

    at Vector.main(Vector.java:7)
```

What is the issue? Do I have to download something?

Comment: Either change your class name to something other than `Vector` or use `java.util.Vector v = new java.util.Vector(3, 2);`. BTW, I would strongly recommend the first, not the second solution.

Comment: One general advice: Don't run programs if there are compilation errors. Work on those errors first.

Comment: By the way, whatever learning material you use, throw it away and look for something better as it seems to be hopelessly outdated. This API has been superseded by the Collection API over 15 years ago. The need to call `new Integer(…)`, `new Float(…)` or `new Double(…)` has been removed ten years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your class name is also `Vector`, compiler couldn't resolve `java.util.Vector`.
Change your code as

```
java.util.Vector v = new java.util.Vector(3, 2);
```

Answer (score 6):

In naming your own class `Vector` you are shadowing the name of `java.util.Vector` - so every unqualified reference you make to `Vector` means your own class - and that doesn't have an `(int,int)`-constructor.

To remedy this you technically have two options:

- either qualify each use of `java.util.Vector` like

  java.util.Vector v = new java.util.Vector(3, 2);
- rename your own class to `MyVectorTestProgram` or something like that

But the first one isn't really a valid option - it is terribly bad programming style to use the same name as core-classes of the java-library for that will almost always generate the very same problem you experience now.

Answer (score 2):

Your class is **also named '`Vector`'**. It's *Shadowing Declarations* in Java.

See:[Java Language Specification - 6.3.1 Shadowing Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html#6.3.1)

> A declaration d of a type named n shadows the declarations of any
>   other types named n that are in scope at the point where d occurs
>   throughout the scope of d.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if you got runtime errors or compilation errors, but you are confusing the compiler by importing `java.util.*` which contains `java.util.Vector` and calling your class Vector. It would be best to rename your class.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is using your `Vector` class when you're expecting it to use `java.util.Vector`. Remove the import statement, then run the `Organize Imports` command.

[image]

Comment: What will this achieve? There is no organization of the imports that will make this work; he either needs to reference the fully qualified name java.util.Vector or rename his test class.